# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter alternative

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

In newer versions of Spring Security, the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class has been deprecated and removed. What can replace it? I am teaching Spring Security using a video course, in the video course there is an old version of Spring Boot, or rather version 2.5.1, and I have version Spring Boot 3.2.3, how can I replace this piece of code so that it works the same way on the version I am using?
package ru.alishov.springcourse.FirstSecurityApp.config;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import ru.alishov.springcourse.FirstSecurityApp.services.PersonDetailsService;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    private final PersonDetailsService personDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(PersonDetailsService personDetailsService)
    { this.personDetailsService = personDetailsService; }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    { auth.userDetailsService(personDetailsService); }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder()
    { return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance(); }
 }
```

Comment: See https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: You can use SecurityFilterChain with HttpSecurity, you can see this: https://github.com/dinhphu28/blog-be/blob/develop/src%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Ftech%2Fdinhphu28%2Fblog%2Fconfig%2FSecurityConfig.java

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Security 5.7.0, Spring deprecated the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

**It encourages a component-based security configuration.**

You can see this:
https://github.com/behrouztakhti/spring-security